# JGRASP is telling me using public or private when referencing a component or variable is wrong

Tags: java, private, public, jgrasp

```
 private class RoutinePanel extends JPanel
 {

  public RoutinePanel()
  {

      //labels
    private JLabel messageLabel;

      //constants for Routine Charges

    private final double OIL_CHANGE_CHARGE = 26.0;
    private final double LUBE_JOB_CHARGE = 18.0;
    private final double RADIATOR_FLUSH_CHARGE = 30.0;
    private final double TRANS_FLUSH_CHARGE = 80.0;
    private final double INSPECTION_CHARGE = 15.0;
    private final double MUFFLER_CHARGE = 100.0;
    private final double TIRE_ROTATION_CHARGE = 20.0;
```

JGRASP is telling me that using private in this case is an illegal operation.`My teacher specifically told us to create it that way, however. If needed I can provide the pseudo code we received from the professor.

I have also tried replacing private with public.

error message the same for all lines containing private

JoesAutomotive.java:57: error: illegal start of expression

```
  private JLabel messageLabel;
```

Comment: It is telling you what, exactly? Not a paraphrase. The exact literal error message.

Comment: @EJP sorry I added the error and the actual code that's wrong. I don't know how the first set of code got in there.

Comment: OK now look again, carefully. It is not saying that `private` is an illegal operation. It is saying that, *at the token `private`,* you have an illegal start of an expression. It isn't the same thing at all. The reason is that you can't have private inside a method. And note also that you are *not* 'referencing a component or variable' as per your title. You are *defining* one. Precision please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private` and `public` are illegal inside a method definition (in this case, the constructor for `RoutinePanel`.)

You need to declare class member variables in the class, outside of any method definition. Like:

```java
private class RoutinePanel extends JPanel
{

  //labels
  private JLabel messageLabel;

  //constants for Routine Charges
  private final double OIL_CHANGE_CHARGE = 26.0;
  // ...

  public RoutinePanel()
  {
```

Comment: thank you so much. Unfortunately now I'm getting an entirely different error on a different part of my code.